# Hazelcast Aggregations API results in ClassCastException with Predicates

Tags: hazelcast

I'm using a Hazelcast `IMap` instance to hold objects like the following:

```java
public class Report implements Portable, Comparable<Report>, Serializable 
{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String sourceId;
    private Date timestamp;
    private Map<String,Object> payload;
  // ...
}
```

The `IMap` is keyed by the `id`, and I have also created an index on `sourceId`, as I need to query and aggregate based on that field.

```java
IMap<String, Report> reportMap = hazelcast.getMap("reports");
reportMap.addIndex("sourceId", false);
```

I've been trying to use the Aggregations framework to count reports by `sourceId`.  **Attempt #1:**

```java
  public static int reportCountforSource(String sourceId) 
  {
      EntryObject e = new PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject();
      Predicate<String, Report> predicate = e.get("sourceId").equal(sourceId);
      Supplier<String, Report, Object> supplier = Supplier.fromPredicate(predicate);
      Long count = reportMap.aggregate(supplier, Aggregations.count());

      return count.intValue();
  }
```

This resulted in a `ClassCastException` being thrown by the Aggregations framework:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.hazelcast.mapreduce.aggregation.impl.SupplierConsumingMapper$SimpleEntry cannot be cast to com.hazelcast.query.impl.QueryableEntry
    at com.hazelcast.query.Predicates$AbstractPredicate.readAttribute(Predicates.java:859) 
    at com.hazelcast.query.Predicates$EqualPredicate.apply(Predicates.java:779) 
    at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.aggregation.impl.PredicateSupplier.apply(PredicateSupplier.java:58) 
    at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.aggregation.impl.SupplierConsumingMapper.map(SupplierConsumingMapper.java:55)
    at com.hazelcast.mapreduce.impl.task.KeyValueSourceMappingPhase.executeMappingPhase(KeyValueSourceMappingPhase.java:49)
```

I then changed to use `Predicates` instead of `PredicateBuilder().getEntryObject()` for **Attempt #2:**

```java
  public static int reportCountforSource(String sourceId) 
  {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      Predicate<String, Report> predicate = Predicates.equal("sourceId", sourceId);
      Supplier<String, Report, Object> supplier = Supplier.fromPredicate(predicate);
      Long count = reportMap.aggregate(supplier, Aggregations.count());

      return count.intValue();
  }
```

This resulted in the same `ClassCastException`.

Finally, I used a lambda to implement the `Predicate` interface in **Attempt #3:**

```java
  public static int reportCountforSource(String sourceId) 
  {
      Predicate<String, Report> predicate = (entry) ->  entry.getValue().getSourceId().equals(sourceId);
      Supplier<String, Report, Object> supplier = Supplier.fromPredicate(predicate);
      Long count = reportMap.aggregate(supplier, Aggregations.count());

      return count.intValue();
  }
```

This attempt finally works.

**Question #1:**  Is this a bug in Hazelcast?  It seems that the Aggregations framework should support a `Predicate` constructed from either `Predicates` or `PredicateBuilder`?  If not, then a new type should be created (e.g., `AggregationPredicate`) to avoid this kind of confusion.

**Question #2 (related to #1):**  Using the lambda `Predicate` results in the index I created not being used.  Instead, each entry within the map is being deserialized to determine if it matches the `Predicate`, which slows things down quite a bit.  Is there any way to create a `Supplier` from a `Predicate` that will use the index?  (**EDIT:**  I verified that each entry is being deserialized by putting a counter in the `readPortable` method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this looks like a Hazelcast bug. I guess I never created a unittest to test a Predicate created by PredicateBuilder. Can you please file an issue at github?

Currently indexes are not supported on mapreduce, whatever you try. The indexing system will be rewritten in the near future to also support all kinds of non-primitive indexes like partial or stuff.

Another thing that is not yet available is an optimized reader for Portable objects which would prevent full deserialization.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Filed: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/5010

Comment: The fix has been just merged to the Hazelcast master and will be released in the forthcoming 3.6 release. Thx for reporting it!